# Data from two tables into two columns

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have a table with sentences describing the condition of the building. Some of these sentences belong to the category of "complete" and some belong to the category of "preparing". I also have two tables (complete, preparing), which include building ID and sentence ID. So each building is described by two tables (complete, preparing). I would like to create a query whose result will have two columns -> description of the building.

```
-----------       -----------------------     ----------------------
 SENTENCES              COMPLETE                     PREPARING
-----------       -----------------------     ----------------------
ID  |  text       ID_HOUSE  | ID_SENTENCES     ID_HOUSE | ID_SENTENCES
-----------       ------------------------    ------------------------                
1   |  One            1     |       1               1   |       3
2   |  Two            1     |       2               2   |       1
3   |  Tree           2     |       2
```

I would like something like this:  (for house 1)

```
COMPLETE     |      PREPARING
------------------------------
   One       |         Tree
   Two       |         NULL
```

I created this, but it does not work.

```
SELECT s.text AS complete, 
(
  SELECT s.text
  FROM sentences AS s
  LEFT JOIN preparing AS p ON s.id = p.id_sentences
  WHERE s.id_house = 1
) AS preparing
FROM sentences AS s
LEFT JOIN complete AS c ON s.id = c.sentences
WHERE s.id_house = 1
```

This is what I get

> ## 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

**Scheme**

I tried to make a diagram, but unfortunately I do not have enough reputation points to upload, so it is hidden here: .

[Scheme](http://www.theego.cz/scheme.png)

Answer (score 0):

That's true you'll get more than one row since you are using left join, in Complete you have 2 ID's with value 1 and left join gives you all the rows from Complete with value 1. What is the query actually you want, I haven't quite understood what your query I mean the output you wanted. (Also what are the foreign keys in that)

Comment: Hello, foreign keys are ID_HOUSE and ID_SENTENCES. ID_SENTENCES is from table SENTENCES and ID_HOUSE is from table HOUSES (There are not given here.) What I would like is list two columns containing the data from the "Sentences". These data are for individual buildings specified in the tables COMPLETE and PREPARING.

Comment: your naming convention is a bit confusing to me, is s.id_house is same as s.id, can you list which columns are associated to each other because in Sentences you have ID which ID? ID_house or ID_sentences and your Houses table where do you use it.

Comment: Hello, I added a simple scheme, sorry for the confused description.